# Can't call Spring's Controller method using Ajax

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I am very new to Ajax and I need some help. I need to call a controller method using Ajax and show the output as response on a JSP page. Given below is the piece of code that I tried, but I couldn't make it work.

Server Code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/home.do",method=RequestMethod.POST,params="custdetails")
public  @ResponseBody ModelAndView getCustomderDetails(@RequestParam("str")   String custId,@ModelAttribute("customerdropdown") CustomerNameDropDown cdropdown)
{
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("CustomerDetails");
    List listCustomerDetails=new ArrayList();
    List<Object[]> CustomerDetailsList = new ArrayList<Object[]>(); 

    CustomerDetailsList=customerDetailsService.getCustomerDetails(custId);

    mav.addObject("custregistration", cdropdown);
    mav.addObject("customerdetailslist", CustomerDetailsList);
    return mav;
}
```

Client Code

```
function getCustomerDetails(str) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (str=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="Please Enter All Fields..";
            }
        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("POST","home.do?custdetails"+"&age="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Comment: You didn't include your JavaScript code.

Comment: I am able to call the getCustomerDetails(str) function from my jsp page successfully,the issue is in the next step i.e unable to call the controller method. I have included that portion of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the `@RequestParam("str")` to `@RequestParam("age")` inside your controller method, the value of the request param is the name of the request parameter which in your case is *age* `xmlhttp.open("POST","home.do?custdetails"+"&age="+str,true);`

You can change the parameter name in the request to `xmlhttp.open("POST","home.do?custdetails"+"&str="+str,true);` but I guess that the former is more proper as you've most likely confused parameter name and parameter value in your mapping

If your intent was to make the RequestParam optional, you should explicitely define it, as `@RequestParam(value="age", required=false)` otherwise its mandatory

Comment: How will that make any difference?

Comment: well  without it won't call the controller method :) Your controller method will be called for the POST request with the path home.do, and parameters custdetails and str. So the only thing that doesn't match is the last parameter which in your request is not str rather age. Seems that you've mixed the value and the name of the parameter in your mapping.

Comment: Thanks buddy,the parameter name mismatch was the reason. :)

Comment: you welcome, glad you've resolved it